# Integration of Wigner matrices

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I need to calculate the integral:

$$\int_{S(2)}D_{m_1,n_1}^{j_1}(U)D_{m_2,n_2}^{j_2}(U)dU$$

where $D_{m_i,n_i}^{j_i}(U)$ are Wigner D-matrices. [I am told](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.05268) (page 12) that there is a formula for the product of 4 D-matrices

$$\int_{S(2)}D_{m_1,n_1}^{j_1}(U)D_{m_2,n_2}^{j_2}(U)D_{m_3,n_3}^{j_3}(U)D_{m_4,n_4}^{j_4}(U)dU = \sum_J(2J+1)i^{J,j_1,j_2,j_3,j_4}_{m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4}i^{J,j_1,j_2,j_3,j_4}_{n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4}$$
where $i^{J,j_1,j_2,j_3,j_4}_{m_1,m_2,m3,m_4}$ are Wigner 3j symbols.

Is there something analogous for the product of two D-matrices?

**More in general** Where can I find tables for formulae for D-matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the integral over $SU(2)$ rather than $S(2)$ (the two sphere)? If so, the $D$ matrices are orthogonal, in the sense that
$$
\int_{SU(2)}[D^{j_1}_{m_1 n_1}(U)]^*D^{j_2}_{m_2 n_2}(U)\,dU = \frac{8\pi^2}{2j_1+1}\delta^{j_1j_2}\delta_{m_1n_1}\delta_{m_2n_2}
$$
where $dU$ is the normalised Haar measure on $SU(2)$. In addition, $D^j_{mn}(U) = (-1)^{m-n}[D^j_{-m,-n}(U)]^*$. Combining these two results will give the equation you're looking for.

More generally, the product $D^{j_1}_{m_1 n_1}(U)D^{j_2}_{m_2 n_2}(U)$ (without the integral) is given by the Clebsch-Gordon series: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix) for details.